# Seeking open source alternative to Spatial Analyst / 3D Analyst toolbox of ArcGIS Desktop

Tags: dem, software-recommendations, interpolation, open-source-gis

Is there a decent open source software alternative for the Spatial
Analyst / 3D Analyst toolboxes of the ArcGIS environment?

The main goal would be to demonstrate DEM interpolation and/or triangulation from an unstructured point cloud.

Answer (score -1):

Consider [white box tools](https://jblindsay.github.io/ghrg/WhiteboxTools/index.html), this allows you to do many of the spatial analyst type processing without the expensive esri spatial analyst extension. They have even created a python toolbox so you can use the tools in modelbuilder or as stand alone tools.